# TFS Error after migration - TF250016 on Reports Site in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, migration, report

Good day all,

We recently migrated from TFS2008 to TFS2010. We migrated our TFS_name databases and our WSS databases. We followed the migration steps and our upgrade was successful, except for a single piece regarding the project sites.

Whenever I go into a team project portal, I receive the following error when trying to access the "Reports" site.

`TF250016: No access rights have been granted for the following site: http://<tfsserver>/Sites/<project portal site>. You must grant access rights between the SharePoint Web application and Team Foundation Server. You must also associate this site with reports and dashboards for a specific project in Team Foundation Server. For more information, see the Microsoft Web site (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=147580).`

I have gone through the TFS upgrade steps and made sure we followed every step and we are running of ideas. Can anyone point me in the right direction? We didn't notice this error as we are not using reports at this time, but it's something we would like to implement in the future.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

(to read in the comments)

You did a move from one server to another and upgrade your TFS Server. 
It's most likely you didn't follow the "[how to move a TFS from one hardware configuration to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx)" procedure, then you'r SQL Report Server is down or incorrectly configured (the SQL Connection strings in the Data Sources configuration are incorrect).

Follow the procedure I gave you for the SQS Server Resport Service part and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it did not help. When trying the "Repair" function, I receive the following:

`Reconnecting SharePoint Web application at the following address: http://<servername>/.
Reconnect operation succeeded`

Also, when looking at the reporting module and then pressing "Edit" and "Test Connection" I receive the following:

Use Reporting (checkbox enabled)
1. On Warehouse Tab: The Database you specified cannot be used, the database exists, but it's schema is not valid for use with TFS. (refering back to Tfs_Warehouse. 
2. On Analysis Services Tab: Same error on TFS_Analysis DB

Comment: Did you also migrate SQL Server from 2005 to 2008 ?

Comment: yes we did. We received a new server and we installed SQL Server 2008 on it. Then we simply backed up the Dbs, copied them over to the new machine, restored them, and kicked off the upgrade process for TFS2010 through the wizard. Did we miss a step?

Comment: ok, to be clear: before you add one server with SQL+TFS, then you got a new server, installed SQL, restore the data from the old server and install TFS on the same box, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Our old server had SQL 2005 + TFS 2008, then we got a new server. We installed SQL 2008 on it, restored the data from the old server and installed TFS 2010 on the same machine. Then we kicked off the upgrade process through the TFS 2010 install disk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11588/discussion-between-nockawa-and-frankie-c)